# Check Box to be selected row index manner in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to select the check box values in row index manner in a grid view, Can someone suggest how to select the checkbox? Please find below the code not working appropraitely.

```
        function Check_Click(spanChk) {
            {
                var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;

                var Chk = spanChk;

                Parent = document.getElementById('Gv1');

                var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>');

                var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
                var i = 0;
                var tot = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    if (items[i].checked) {
                        tot = tot + 1;

                        if (tot > 2) {
                            alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');
                            items[i].checked = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

This is my grid view file

```
         <asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gv1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datedif" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour1").ToString().Equals("False") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour2").ToString().Equals("False") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox6_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour3").ToString().Equals("False") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour4").ToString().Equals("False") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour5").ToString().Equals("False") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox5_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Could you please comment on the code lines that what you want to perform with those lines?

Comment: That isn't C# code Ravi.

Comment: Can you use jquery instead javascript ?

Comment: Am doing timetable management for my college.This is the last part of timetable, the condition is staff cannot book the subject not more than 2 times in a day and per week he can take 12 subject for that only am trying this java script. Javascript or Jquery can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `JavaScript` function from all of the `CheckBoxes` as shown below,

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gv1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datedif" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn1" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour1" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour1").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkColumn2" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour2" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour2").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox6_CheckedChanged" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn3" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour3" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour3").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn4" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour4" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour4").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn5" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour5" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour5").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox5_CheckedChanged" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And in the `JavaScript`, validate the selected `CheckBox` with its `Row` and then validate the number of items selected.

```
     function IdExists(elements, id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].id.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function Check_Click(chkBx) {
        Parent = document.getElementById('<% =Gv1.ClientID %>');
        for (i = 0; i < Parent.rows.length; i++) {

            var row = Parent.rows[i];
            var items = row.getElementsByTagName('input');

            if (items.length > 0) {
                if (IdExists(items, chkBx.id)) {
                    var tot = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {

                        if (items[j].type == 'checkbox' && items[j].checked) {

                            tot = tot + 1;

                            if (tot > 2) {
                                alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');
                                chkBx.checked = false;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RavintherM So you have other `CheckBoxes` in the `GridView`?

Comment: Its checking in column wise when i give the onclick function.If i give that onclick function on gridview it checking in row wise but the problem in ** when i click one checkbox in first row and another checkbox in second row  it showing the status of alert message** what shall i do now

Comment: @RavintherM I have updated the answer. I have added one more condition, validating the `ID` (`chkSelect`) in the `if Condition`. Try something similar for your `CheckBox`.

Comment: same thing is happening its is checking in column wise not row wise

Comment: Am doing timetable management for my college.This is the last part of timetable, the condition is staff cannot book the subject not more than 2 times in a day and per week he can take 12 subject for that only am trying this java script. Javascript or Jquery can be used

Comment: @RavintherM I have updated the Answer. Please change your `CheckBox ID`s as they are duplicated.

Comment: @RavintherM Whats the output now you getting?

Comment: It not checking itself and i changed items[i].id.indexOf('chkHour1') its working but if went to next row same pop up is coming.its not properly validating

Comment: @RavintherM So whats your exact requirement? The code given here is allows you select the `chkColumn1` checkbox in two rows. After that if you click `chkColumn1` checkbox it shows alert message. If you want something different?

Comment: the condition is staff cannot book the subject not more than 2 times in a day and per week he can take 12 subject.

Comment: @RavintherM So more than two checkBoxes not checked in a Row? Not in a column?

Comment: In rows.It checked in column wise only its working if i give onclick in checkbox1 and if i give onclick in grid view its checking for only one row and i cannot go more than that

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class name in the checkbox. then you can easily get all the checkbox by the class name.

```
function Check_Click(spanChk) {
        {
            var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;

           var items = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckBox');
            var i = 0;
            var tot = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].checked) {
                    tot = tot + 1;

                    if (tot > 2) {
                        alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');
                        items[i].checked = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

you can also use the below code to get all the checkbox.

```
var Checkboxes =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```